# Find function $g(x)$, if $g(x) = f(f(x))$

Tags: functions

$g(x) = f(f(x))$. Find function $g$ as a formula and draw its graph, if:

$f(x) = 3 + x$, if $x \le 0$ and $f(x) = 3 - x$, if $x \gt 0$

I tried to used l'Hopital's rule, but that led me to a dead-end. Any ideas?

Comment: Calculate $f(f(x))$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: How does this question have any relationship whatsoever to limits, and why were you using l'Hopital's rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why do you want to use l'Hopital's rule as this question does not involved limit at all.

Guide:

Evaluate $f(-3)$, $f(0)$ and $f(3)$ separately.

Then, consider $4$ cases, $x < -3$, $-3<x<0$, $0<x<3$, $x>3$.

For example, let me consider the case where $x<-3$,

$$f(f(x))=f(3+x)$$

Since $3+x<0$,

$$f(3+x)=3+(3+x)=6+x$$

Try to do similar stuff for the other $3$ cases.

Edit:

Case $2$:

If $x>3$, then $3-x <0$, hence $$f(f(x))=f(3-x)=3+(3-x)$$

Case $3$:

If $0<x<3$, then $3-x>0$, hence $$f(f(x))=f(3-x)=3-(3-x)$$

Comment: So $f(x-3) = x - 6$, but how do create the functions for the intervals?
Also, once I find out f(f(x)) for each case, how do I represent all of them in $g(x)$ and graph it?

Comment: which case are you considering? $f(x-3)=x-6$ is not true for all $x$.  when you plot $g(x)$, you consider the interval separately, each interval might follow different rule.

Comment: When $x \gt 3$, then $f(x-3) = x-6$. What about the second and third interval case? I'm not sure about them.
Also, when I consider each interval separately for each four case, do I also get four different $g$ functions?
I have the urge to mention that my Erdos number is 28.

Comment: when $x>3$, $f(f(x))=f(3-x)$. When $x$ is in the first interval, you follow rule $g_1$, if it is in the scond interval, it follows rule $g_2$ and so on.

Comment: Last question. When $-3 \lt x \lt 0$, $f(f(x)) = f(x^2 - 3x)$ and when $0 \lt x \lt 3$, $f(f(x)) = f(x^2 + 3x).$ Is that correct?

Comment: you should not get quadratic terms. try again?

Comment: 1) $x \lt -3$, then $3+x \lt 0$; 
2) $x \gt 3$, then $3 - x \gt 0$; 
3) $0 \lt x \lt 3$, then $3 + 2x \gt 0$; 
4) $0 \lt x \lt -3$, then $-3 + 2x \lt 0$

Comment: Case $1$ is correct and you already have the answer. Caase $2$, $x>3$, we have $3-x<0$. case $3$, $3+2x$ is positive is correct but I don't see the relevance to the question. Similar for case $4$. I have included more details for case $2$ and $3$.